# Find and rm command not obeying exclude list occassionally

Tags: shell-script, find, cron

I am running a find and rm -rf directory list modified earlier than 7 days with an exclusion list of directories which should not be deleted at any case.

This is the script excerpt

```
find [path-to-base-dir] -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name [dir1] ! -name .snapshot \
! -name . ! -name [dir2] ! -name [dir3] ! -name [dir4] ! -name [dir5] ! -name [dir6] \
! -name [dir7] ! -name [dir8] ! -name [dir9] ! -name [dir10] ! -name [dir11] ! -name [dir12]\
 -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \; -print
```

This is scheduled as a daily cron. On most days, this works fine.. But on some days it ignores the exclusion list and deletes all directories. How can this happen? The condition list is very long, so any kind of latency can lead to find command ignoring the !name conditions..?

Comment: Small tip: Rather than `-print` you can use the `-v` option to `rm` to simplify the command.

Comment: Do you give the base path as a relative or absolute path? How do you give the exclusions? Relative or absolute?

Comment: I worry re this part `! -name .` What that mean in your script? If you wants to exclude base dir you should better use `-mindepth 1` parameter.

Comment: @Costas, or use `find "$basedir/."` or `cd -P -- "$basedir" && find .`, not all `find` implementations have `-mindepth`.

Comment: Is the command static or generated? Are there any special characters (including whitespace, dashes, exclamation marks etc) in *any* of the directory names?

Comment: Static. This script is not edited in the last several months. It works fine most of the days. We have had the full deletion for 4-5 times in the last 1 year. The unwarranted deletion has a big impact though.
Could a change in the modify date of the directories nullify the exemption?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> find path-to-base-dir -maxdepth 1 \
>      -type d ! -name bunch-of-exceptions \
>      -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \; -print
> ```

You did not include `path-to-base-dir` in the `bunch-of-exceptions`. (You included `.` but that would only match if `path-to-base-dir` was exactly `.`) The only condition that the directory `path-to-base-dir` might fail if `-mtime +7`. If the directory happens not to have been modified in the last 7 days, it will be deleted.

Since your `find` has `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`, use `-mindepth 1` to exclude the starting directory.

Comment: Thank you.
Yes the issue was with '! -name .'
It was not including the parent directory, unless the command is run from the same location, and that too only if 'find .' is used; if you use absolute path for find and use '! -name .' for matching, that will also fail. Our intermittent delete issue was due to the fact that most of the days the parent directory was excluded due to the last 7-days modified condition, and not because we had '.' in exclusion. the parent directory gets modified if any file or directory is added/deleted directly under it.
thanks again. thanks to costas and other too.

Answer (score 0):

Put those `[dir1]` strings in quotes, otherwise the shell will try to expand them because of the brackets, which may or may not succeed according to the contents of your current working directory.

Comment: I doubt OP meant *literally* `[dir1]`.

Comment: Sorry, the directory names are different, e.g., suggestapp, content, etc. I just represented them here like [dirx]. '.' is used to exclude current directory and .snapshot to exclude some nfs backups. We dont use quotes for the file names, but as I said this works fine most of the days. Fails in a few days with no pattern, maybe once in a month or 2 times a week, and so on.